# KDE is not saving a mime-type file association

Tags: kde, mime-types, plasma5

I'm running Arch Linux and KDE and I am exploring how mime-types are behaving (and misbehaving) on my system.

Consider this mime-type file association. The following console output shows that I have the mime-type xml definition file and there is an association between `.pub` files and the mime-type `application/vnd.ms-publisher`.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test.pub
application/vnd.ms-publisher

$ less mimeapps.list
[Added Associations]
application/vnd.ms-publisher=org.kde.kate.desktop;

# find /usr -name vnd.ms-publisher.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml

# less /usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="application/vnd.ms-publisher">
<!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
<sub-class-of type="application/x-ole-storage"/>
<glob pattern="*.pub"/>
</mime-type>
```

(I do not like the fact that ms-publisher is associated with public keys on my Linux system, but that's the topic of another question.)

It would appear from the above that all is in order.

Next I decided to **add an association for Kate (text editor) to handle `.pub` public key files**. I created this using KDE System Settings > Applications > File Associations.

This screen shot shows what I did. When I clicked "Apply" the progress dialog appears briefly and the action seems to have succeeded.

[image: Add File Association]

**However, upon revisiting that same dialog, the Kate association I just added is gone.** The box under "Application Preference Order" is empty.

[image: My Added Association Is Gone]

**My question is: what is causing this file association to not be saved, and how can I fix it?**

Checking `journalctl -r` I found the following messages (in reverse order). All lines start with a prefix simlarl to `Jan 31 17:24:18 laptop systemsettings5[20318]` but I removed most of those to save space.

```
Jan 31 17:24:19 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: Mimetype Comment Dirty: old= "Kindle book document" m_comment= "Amazon KF8 ebook format"
Jan 31 17:24:19 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: Mimetype Comment Dirty: old= "ODB database" m_comment= "OpenDocument Database"
Jan 31 17:24:19 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:24:19 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:24:19 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: ("services", "servicetypes", "xdgdata-mime", "apps")

...

Jan 31 17:24:18 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: "application/vnd.ms-publisher" hasDefinitionFile: false
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-xm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/x-rst"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/pdf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bzip"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cue"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-rgb"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-gzpdf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cmakecache"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sigma-x3f"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-tellico"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-flat-xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-mswrite"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-t602"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-nikon-nef"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-flic"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/video-vcd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/flac"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/xspf+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/svg+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-xpixmap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.calc"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/gzip"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-zip-compressed-fb2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-wavpack"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/vnd.rn-realvideo"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-pic"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.draw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kexi-connectiondata"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-mobipocket-ebook"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/ac3"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-win-bitmap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.kde.okular-archive"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-zstd-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/mpeg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/mlt-playlist"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-kde-raw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-7z-compressed"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/vnd.rn-realaudio"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-panasonic-rw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/x-patch"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kdenlivetitle"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/blank-cd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-asf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/quicktime"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/vnd.djvu"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-anim"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/plain"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-java-keystore"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-archive"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-sv4crc"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.appimage"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.visio"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-tga"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-zoom"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/heif"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/rle"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/csv"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.lotus-wordpro"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/aac"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-icns"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-tta"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cbt"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/tiff"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/ogg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-wpl"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-pentax-pef"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-olympus-orf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/pgp-keys"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-jng"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-lz4-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-font-pcf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/xhtml+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-java"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sgi"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/basic"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-executable"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/spreadsheet"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-ms-wma"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-fuji-raf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-compress"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/vnd.dts"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/fits"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xz"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/gif"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-ms-asx"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-mng"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-gimp-gbr"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bzpdf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/png"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-gzdvi"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/mxf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-wpg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-xwindowdump"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-dcraw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-mpegurl"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/audio-player"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/blank-dvd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/cgm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-fictionbook+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.palm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/webm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/wmf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/tab-separated-values"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-pagemaker"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.comicbook-rar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/openraster"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/illustrator"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-publisher"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/msword"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-krita"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-dvi"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-portable-bitmap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/AMR"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cpio"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/webp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/css"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-adobe-dng"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-eps"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-compressed-xcf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-quattropro"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-ms-dos-executable"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-access"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-sv4cpio"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/mp4"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.comicbook+zip"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xojpp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bzdvi"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-gimp-pat"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-gimp-gih"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.math"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/vnd.zbrush.pcx"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-flv"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/audio-cdda"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/jpeg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sony-arw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/emf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sony-srf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-panasonic-rw2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/prs.plucker"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-flat-xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/dv"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-trash"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/pgp-encrypted"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-dds"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-xcursor"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/midi"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-kodak-dcr"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.rn-realmedia"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/smil+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-font-bdf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/octet-stream"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-k3b"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-it"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bzpostscript"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.amazon.mobi8-ebook"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.rar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.impress"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-musepack"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sun-raster"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/pgp-signature"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/zip"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cd-image"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-rpm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/mathml+xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-xcf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-nsv"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-scpls"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-speex"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-flat-xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-shorten"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-wav"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-canon-cr2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/epub+zip"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-photo-cd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-adpcm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "font/ttf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.stardivision.writer"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/jp2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/video-svcd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/javascript"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/bmp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-portable-anymap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-gsm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/mp4"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/sdp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-xbitmap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-bzeps"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-msvideo"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xpinstall"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/svg+xml-compressed"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.debian.binary-package"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-matroska"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-s3m"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-ksysguard"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-keepass2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/mp2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-kodak-k25"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/blank-hddvd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/x-google-video-pointer"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/blank-bd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/html"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-works"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-flac+ogg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-gzpostscript"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/vcard"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-sony-sr2"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "inode/directory"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xopp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kdenlive"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.corel-draw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.wordperfect"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-minolta-mrw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.sqlite3"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-portable-pixmap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/vnd.qt.linguist"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-canon-crw"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "x-content/video-dvd"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.kde.fontspackage"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/oxps"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-khtml-adaptor"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/mp2t"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-mod"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/vnd.rn-realpix"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/postscript"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-lzma"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/AMR-WB"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-aiff"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-portable-graymap"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/markdown"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-bcpio"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-lzip-compressed-tar"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/x-matroska"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-stm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/prs.sid"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-ape"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-designer"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "text/x-ldif"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kexiproject-shortcut"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-font-type1"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-exr"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-kodak-kdc"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-cb7"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-gzeps"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-xopt"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-flat-xml"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/x-hdr"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "multipart/x-mixed-replace"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-iso9660-appimage"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-java-applet"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-sony-bbeb"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kwallet"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-tzo"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/vnd.mpegurl"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-dbf"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-hwp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-navi-animation"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-font-afm"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "audio/x-opus+ogg"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/ram"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "multipart/mixed"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "image/fax-g3"

...

Jan 31 17:24:18 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:24:18 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:24:18 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: Entry  "application/vnd.ms-publisher"  is dirty. Saving.
Jan 31 17:21:57 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:21:57 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: kf5.kservice.services: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/vnd.ms-publisher" not found
Jan 31 17:21:57 laptop systemsettings5[20318]: "application/vnd.ms-publisher" hasDefinitionFile: false
```

Some notable messages  from the above include:

```
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/vnd.ms-publisher"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/illustrator"
```

I have already shown that the mime type `application/vnd.ms-publisher` is present and defined. So I checked a few more at random. Here is `application/illustrator` (with comments removed to save space).

```
less /usr/share/mime/application/illustrator.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="application/illustrator">
<!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
<generic-icon name="image-x-generic"/>
<glob pattern="*.ai"/>
<alias type="application/vnd.adobe.illustrator"/>
</mime-type>
```

All the mime-type definitions seems to be present according to a listing of `ls /usr/share/mime/application/` (There is not sufficient space to post the entire directory listing here.)

I do not understand why the log messages indicate "Service type not found" for mime-types that are present on my system. But more importantly, why can I not add an application to handle the mime type as shown above?

Response to comments by Nathaniel M. Beaver

```
$ ktraderclient5 --mimetype application/vnd.ms-publisher
mimetype is : application/vnd.ms-publisher
got 1 offers.
---- Offer 0 ----
Invalid property Actions
StartupNotify : 'TRUE'
StartupWMClass : 'libreoffice-draw'
Invalid property UntranslatedGenericName
Invalid property X-GIO-NoFuse
X-KDE-Protocols : 'file - http - ftp - webdav - webdavs'
Type : 'Application'
Name : 'LibreOffice Draw'
Comment : 'Create and edit drawings, flow charts, and logos by using Draw.'
GenericName : 'Drawing Program'
Icon : 'libreoffice-draw'
Exec : 'libreoffice --draw %U'
Terminal : 'FALSE'
Invalid property TerminalOptions
Invalid property Path
ServiceTypes : 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-flat-xml - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template - application/vnd.sun.xml.draw - application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template - application/vnd.visio - application/x-wpg - application/vnd.corel-draw - application/vnd.ms-publisher - image/x-freehand - application/clarisworks - application/x-pagemaker - application/pdf - application/x-stardraw - image/x-emf - image/x-wmf - Application'
AllowAsDefault : 'TRUE'
InitialPreference : '5'
Invalid property Library
DesktopEntryPath : '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop'
DesktopEntryName : 'libreoffice-draw'
Keywords : 'Vector - Schema - Diagram - Layout - OpenDocument Graphics - Microsoft Publisher - Microsoft Visio - Corel Draw - cdr - odg - svg - pdf - vsd'
FormFactors : ''
Categories : 'Office - FlowChart - Graphics - 2DGraphics - VectorGraphics - X-Red-Hat-Base - X-MandrivaLinux-Office-Drawing'
```

What is the recommended way to remove this?

Comment: Are you by any chance using GNU stow or another symlink manager? https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=419144 Also, you can try enabling debug messages. https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-enable-qdebug-messages-qt

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver - I am not using GNU stow or any symlink manager. Thanks for the link about debug messages.

Comment: Good to know. Note that kde-open5 uses a cache, which can be removed with e.g. `rm ~/.cache/ksycoca5*`.

Comment: Also, output of `ktraderclient5 --mimetype application/vnd.ms-publisher`?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Those are both very helpful comments. I updated the question with the output of `ktraderclient5 --mimetype application/vnd.ms-publisher`. What do you recommend for removing that association and replacing it with my desired public key type? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the output of `grep 'application/vnd.ms-publisher' ~/.config/mimeapps.list` and then try `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime default org.kde.kate.desktop application/vnd.ms-publisher`. See if that helps matters, and re-run the grep command to see if anything changed.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize you already did that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565353/how-to-associate-a-new-custom-mime-type-with-files-based-on-file-extension Might be worth a try, anyway.

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer. If you have a chance, please update your question to explain what ultimately ended up solving your issue. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver - I will provide updates and continue this dialog with you until all my mime type issues are fully resolved. Thanks for your interest in this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same here on completely different system. Do this as regular user:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/mime/packages
update-mime-database $HOME/.local/share/mime
```

(the `mkdir` step may not be necessary if the directory already exists).

If you need full reset, do this:

```
cd $HOME/.local/share/
mv mime mime2
mkdir -p mime/packages
update-mime-database $HOME/.local/share/mime
```

This will reset all your mime corrupted settings, but it will work on.
Currently KDE doesn't call to update the database after making changes, leading to this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a step-by-step approach to debugging mimetype association problems.

1. Determine the file's mimetype.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query filetype ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   application/vnd.ms-publisher
   ```
2. Determine the default handler for the mimetype.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   libreoffice-writer.desktop
   ```

   Add the `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` environment variable for more information.

   ```
   $ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   Running KDE trader query "application/vnd.ms-publisher" mimetype and "Application" servicetype
   libreoffice-writer.desktop
   ```
3. Use `xdg-mime` to change the default association.

   ```
   $ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime default org.kde.kate.desktop application/vnd.ms-publisher
   make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
   make_default_generic org.kde.kate.desktop application/vnd.ms-publisher
   Updating /home/nathaniel/.config/mimeapps.list
   ```

   This can also be done with graphical programs such as Dolphin. The result is not always the same, as we shall see.
4. Check to see if that changed the default handler.

   If `xdg-mime` was successful, it will look like this:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   org.kde.kate.desktop
   ```

   If it didn't work, you'll see this again.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   libreoffice-writer.desktop
   ```
5. If `xdg-mime` didn't work, it's debugging time. Check this file first:

   `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

   It has these sections: `[Added Associations]`, `[Default Applications]`, and `[Removed Associations]`.

   Let's just quickly `grep` to see what's going on.

   ```
   $ grep 'application/vnd.ms-publisher' ~/.config/mimeapps.list
   application/vnd.ms-publisher=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice-draw.desktop;
   application/vnd.ms-publisher=org.kde.kate.desktop;
   ```

   Hm, that doesn't look right. If we inspect the file further, we see that `xdg-mime` added kate under `[Default Applications]` but not `[Added Associations]`. If we had changed the mimetype using Dolphin / `keditfiletype5 application/vnd.ms-publisher`, we would have observed that it would have added `org.kde.kate.desktop;` before `libreoffice-writer.desktop;` under `[Added Associations]`.

   https://cgit.kde.org/kde-cli-tools.git/tree/keditfiletype/mimetypedata.cpp?id=5d1c3d77798949c21958b60cf78d36fb49c57ea2#n367

   Going by the [FreeDesktop spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html), though, it shouldn't matter; anything under `[Default Applications]` should be the default even if it's not listed in `[Added Associations]`.

   > The [Default Applications] group indicates the default application to
   >   be used for a given mimetype. This is for instance the one that will be started
   >   when double-clicking on a file in a file manager. If the application is no
   >   longer installed, the next application in the list is attempted, and so on.

   So this is probably a bug in KDE, and it appears to be fixed upstream here:

   > Make "Default Applications" in mimeapps.list the preferred applications

   https://phabricator.kde.org/D26690

   This is [probably also a bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/issues/12) in `xdg-mime`, which [is a giant shell script](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-mime.in?id=9816ebb3e6fd9f23e993b8b7fcbd56f92d9c9197#n115) that doesn't get enough attention as it needs to do a tip-top job.

   Anyways, let's fix that line so it says this instead:

   ```
   application/vnd.ms-publisher=org.kde.kate.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice-draw.desktop;
   ```

   Let's see if that helped.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   libreoffice-writer.desktop
   ```

   Hm, why didn't that work?

   It's because `xdg-mime` doesn't check things on its own, it calls whatever tools the desktop uses. On KDE, this is things like `kmimetypefinder5`, `ktraderclient5`, and `kbuildsycoca5`. That last one is important, because it's how KDE builds its mimetype associations cache.

   Note this is not the cache at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`,
   although that is also a mimetype cache, because that location is listed as ["for compatibility, deprecated" in the latest spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html).

   The proper way would be to rebuild KDE's mimetype is this:

   ```
   $ kbuildsycoca5
   ```

   but we can also just delete it instead:

   ```
   $ rm ~/.cache/ksycoca5_*
   ```

   and try again:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.ms-publisher
   org.kde.kate.desktop
   ```

   That looks promising. Now let's try opening an actual file:

   ```
   $ xdg-open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   On KDE, this is [basically the same as](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-open.in?id=9816ebb3e6fd9f23e993b8b7fcbd56f92d9c9197#n123):

   ```
   $ kde-open5 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   This should open in the Kate text editor. Success!
6. What if it still doesn't work?

   On KDE Plasma 5, `xdg-mime query default` just calls `ktraderclient5 --mimetype`. So `ktraderclient5 --mimetype application/vnd.ms-publisher` will provide helpful information, although the output may be voluminous.

   Adding `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` to the `xdg-*` commands may give some better debug output.

   Enabling logging on KDE to get `qDebug` output may help, too.

   ```
   $ if ! test -f ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini; then printf '[Rules]\n*.debug=true\nqt.*.debug=false\n' > ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini; else printf 'Error: ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini already exists.\n'; fi;
   ```

   Also, check what file your application is using. `xdg-open` uses `kde-open5`, but your application may behave differently. For example, it might be looking at an old, deprecation mimetype associations file location:

   - `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

   or maybe an even older location:

   - `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

   You might have to dig through source code or use `strace` to figure out which file the application is actually using.

   If you're using custom mimetypes or custom desktop files, the situation becomes even more complicated.

Answer (score -2):

> I do not understand why the log messages indicate "Service type not
>   found" for mime-types that are present on my system

This could either be a **bug** or due to your files being **corrupted**. My vote would go for corruption.

To be sure, please, try the same procedure in a fresh system and report back if it works.

Then, if you are convinced it's a corruption, try

```
# paccheck --md5sum --quiet
```

which would check installed packages and report the files corrupted or changed. `paccheck` is part of the [pacutils](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=pacutils) package. It is discussed on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks).

Comment: I ran `paccheck` and there are no corrupt files reported. I did not expect there to be as my system is well-maintained. I understand you don't experience this problem on a fresh install. My goal is to fix this installation rather than re-install Arch on this device.